# Were there many users removed in recent days? Was there a cause?

Tags: discussion, reputation, users

This last week, I noticed a large number of reputation changes associated with *user was removed*. I think I lost something like fifty to a hundred magical unicorn points™. Users being removed is not something I notice regularly in my reputation change tab.

Was there anything special the matter or was it just a random week of ‘bad RNG’?

Comment: I had no rep changes due to this, so either I or you should be sad right now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There was an issue in which some inappropriate voting was corrected.

Unfortunately, the user(s) abusing the system had voted for legitimately good questions as well (such as your own), so when the votes for these abusive accounts were deemed invalid, those that were potentially cast in earnest were lost as well.

I apologize to you and to anyone else who was an innocent bystander in all of this.

Comment: I’ld much rather hear the abusing user(s)’(s) apologies but I fear they won’t be able to answer ;D But thanks, that clears up a lot ^^

Comment: You're welcome.  Yeah, not sure if that will happen.  We can always hope.