# Did something happened to Loong's account?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I haven't been active on chem.SE lately so I don't know the current scenario. So, bear with me.

---

**Backstory:** I was going through my old questions for some reviewing. I was looking at [this question of mine](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/54765/structural-representation-of-substituted-benzene). One of the answerers of that question had their account deleted (for some reasons, I don't know). I knew that this question was answered by Loong and NotEvans, so the account was of Loong's(now user7951). I was surprised and confused to see one of the moderator and a long time user having their account deleted.

On seeing this, it came to me as a thought that something was off because he wasn't that active lately (because I used to see him regularly edit questions or answer some nomenclature questions). So, I searched up "Loong" in user search tab and it gave me 2 results:

[image]

1. [Member for 2 months, 35 profile views, 4 answers, Last seen 2 days ago](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/101286/loong)
2. [Member for 7 days, 1 profile view, no answers, Last seen Jan 12 at 16:25](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/103369/loong)

Why new accounts? Why 2 accounts? What happened to the old account?

Comment: You might want to look at this: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4846/4945

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Yes, Loong was removed from the moderator position but why did he(or someone else) deleted/removed his old account? Why did he made new accounts? Also, since his old account was deleted, [was there any rep changes from the voting correction](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3309/were-there-many-users-removed-in-recent-days-was-there-a-cause)?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that Loong's old votes won't have been removed from the system (see: [Meta.SE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126471/312770)). Exactly what Loong did / wants to do with his account(s) is not really our business (as long as he is not doing anything shady, like [I did in the past](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3229?m=38756569#38756569) :-), so only he can tell you the full reason, if he wishes to.

Comment: @orthocresol I've just realized that it was me who upvoted you 16 times on that day, 2017-07-14, the same day I received a mod message regarding targeted votes. I was new to CSE at the time and probably stumbled upon one of your posts and decided to read more from the same author. Sorry for causing a precedent you are still having flashbacks about:)

Comment: @andselisk That is pretty funny! I didn't really mind it ;) I don't really have flashbacks about it, actually I just searched through chat for old conversations about socks (there are a few others where, apparently, I'm somebody's sock or vice versa). None of them are serious, but that's what you'd expect a cheater to say, too, so... \*hides\*

Comment: I call for an immediate suspension of the entire mod team!

Comment: "Why 2 accounts?" – I have no idea what happened there.

Comment: @Loong Well, well, you went from zero accounts to two! :D You mentioned that you connected chat account with the new one you made - now you have 2 accounts on Chemistry.SE, congrats!

Comment: Or maybe three, counting the deleted one. I think undeleting old one would be better idea. Dunno how viable it is in practice, but it's just hidden. And now you made third "undead" account :D It got association bonus and badges from chat, but otherwise is empty.

Comment: So long, so loong …

Comment: What did I just read.